# Is there a name for the process of patterning new words after old ones in ways that don't respect their original etymology?

Tags: etymology, terminology

The words "quadcopter" and "novocaine" have unusual etymologies. "Quadcopter" comes from a combination of *quad* for "four" and *copter* from "helicopter," and "novocaine" comes from *novo* for "new" and *caine* from "cocaine."

What's odd here is that both "copter" and "caine" break apart the original words at a spot that isn't the natural split in their own etymologies. "Helicopter" comes from *helico* and *pter*, and "cocaine" comes from *coca* and *ine*. The splits of "copter" and "caine" make a ton of sense given that they're at syllable boundaries and the new words don't seem at all unusual.

Is there a term for new words like quadcopter and novocaine whose origin involves cleaving an existing word at a spot that doesn't match their etymologically?

Comment: "Motorcade" = "Motor" + "[Caval]cade". Though the split itself seems more correct in this example, the neologism seems to be used mainly to highlight the similarities, and expresses the only real difference (motor vehicles instead of horses, four rotors instead of one, more recently invented cocaine instead of the old stuff). I'm not sure that there's a name for the phenomenon, let alone one where the split happens in an etymologically wrong place (the wrong split seems to be caused by no longer understanding the etymology). Will answer if I have some solid proof of its (non)existence.

Comment: A neoloschism ?

Comment: related: 1. [Looking for a word that describes the merger of two words, is this an example of Portmanteau?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358613/looking-for-a-word-that-describes-the-merger-of-two-words-is-this-an-example-of) 2. [What does “adorkable” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84974/what-does-adorkable-mean-how-popular-is-this-word-to-what-kind-of-objects-an) 3. [What are some uncommon but valid portmanteau words that people use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/what-are-some-uncommon-but-valid-portmanteau-words-that-people-use?rq=1)